# Many programs cant access internet

Tags: internet, windows-10

So, recently, I've had a bit of a problem with applications. Most can't access the internet. Here's a fun little bit of a few of my error messages I get when trying to operate applications:

[image]

I can't log on to any profiles from programs such as Skype, Facebook, etc.

I'm forced to find offline installers for every program I want to install.

I can't check my inbox from my PC, and I can't use any program/driver updaters.

I'm not behind a proxy, and have uninstalled Malwarebytes.

I disabled Bitdefender/Windows firewall, but, no change. Can anyone analyze this, and help me get around this?

Comment: I suppose you have access from other devices, don't you?

Comment: Yeah. Every laptop/desktop.

Comment: Then, try to do the following: 1) Press Windows key + R and enter "cmd" 2) Try "ping google.com" and "ping 8.8.8.8". Let us know the results :)

Comment: Wait, could it be my DNS? This happened around when I changed my DNS.

Comment: It pinged successfully. 4 packets sent, 4 returned.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite probable, then. If the ping responses to 8.8.8.8 but not to "google.com", I'd say it's your DNS.

Comment: It responds to both :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26631/discussion-between-hewbot-and-joseph-christian-hefley).